# Error MySQL: no manda los datos a la BD. PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

espero se encuentren bien. Les escribo ya que estoy teniendo un problema con mi código ya que, (mi teoría) es que no se ejecuta el primer IF del código que verán a continuación.

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';
    $message = '';
            if (!empty($_POST['Id'])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO empleados (id_empleados) VALUES (:Id)";
                $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
                $stmt -> bindParam(':Id',$_POST['Id']);

            if ($stmt -> execute()) {
                    $message = 'Se ha creado su cuenta satisfactoriamente en la pagina';
            }
            else {
                $message = 'Lo sentimos, pero ha ocurrido un problema con la base de datos';
            }
        }

    #$sql = "INSERT INTO empleado(id_empleado) VALUES ('_id')";
    #$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
    #$stmt -> bindParam('_id',$_POST['Id']);

    #$stmt -> execute();
    

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="urf-8">
    <title>Signup</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php if(!empty($message)): 
    ?>
        <p><?= $message ?> </p>
    <?php 
    endif; 
    ?>

    <span> Vuelve al <a href="index.php">menú</a></span>
    <span>o <a href="singup.php">Login</a></span>

    <form action="singup.php" method"post">
        <input type="text" name="Id" placeholder="Crea tu id: ">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

La cuestión aquí es que al ingresar al "sign up" en mi página e ingresar una id de empleado no se guarda en la base de datos. Solo se limpia el espacio donde se ingresa la id.
Aquí el código de la BD:

```
<?php

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cafeteria;','root','');
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die('Connected failed: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: Añade mensajes de depurado para ver qué pasa exactamente en tu script. Por ejemplo, haz un var_dump de $_POST, pinta un mensaje cuando entre en ese if, añádele un else y que te pinte ahí otro mensaje... Con todo esto, debes ser capaz de depurar por ti mismo, identificar el problema y solucionarlo.

Comment: muchas gracias @JoséCarlosPHP , lo he intentado y si llegué a la conclusión de que mi variable "Id" no está mandando los datos, así que no se ejecuta el if y por lo tanto no manda nada a mi BD, la cosa aquí es que no he logrado que mande los datos aún, hice otro php llamado "conect" donde tengo el mismo código de php al inicio para saber si el problema se encontraba en que se ejecutaba primero el if por lo cual la variable estaba vacía, pero aún así no he encontrado solución. Muchas Gracias por tu comentario.